# Check existing primary key in dynamodb

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a array which has list of string 
Example : `["one","two","three","four"]`

Also I have a sample dynamodb structure given below

```
id(primary key)  |   status
one              |  completed
three            |  completed
five             |  completed
six              |  Inprogress
```

**I need to check the string value with the dynamodb primary key whether it is already exist in dynamodb or not(Doing this logic in nodejs)**.

If the string value is already exist in dynamodb don't add it in new array and if its not exist in dynamodb need to add the string in the new array.

In the above example data expeced result is : `["two","four"]`.

Please let me know how can we check the existing data in dynamodb.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but I think you're looking for either the `Exists` parameter in a dynamodb `putItem` request or a conditional operator.

To paraphrase [the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#putItem-property), it's possible to assert that the record does not exist when performing a put-operation:

> "If Exists is false, DynamoDB assumes that the attribute value does
>   not exist in the table. If in fact the value does not exist, then the
>   assumption is valid and the operation succeeds. If the value is found,
>   despite the assumption that it does not exist, the operation fails
>   with a ConditionalCheckFailedException."

Similarly, it should be possible to write more complicated assertions on the operation.

Comment: Yes @david here **I only need to check the data is already exist in dynamodb or not** and i don't need to insert the data using putItem.

Comment: Could you not do this with a dynamodb getItem() request?

Comment: if we do this with dynamodb.getItem() for every request we need to fetch all the data from database then compare the existence.It will create a performance issue.So that i looking on any other options in dynamodb to check the existence data.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using [ConditionExpressions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.SpecifyingConditions.html).

```
var params = {};
params.TableName = "MyTable";
params.Item = { id : { S : 'one' }, status : { S : 'completed' } },
params.ConditionExpression = '#i <> :val';
params.ExpressionAttributeNames = {'#i' : 'id'};
params.ExpressionAttributeValues = {':val' : "one"};

DynamoDB.putItem(params, function (error, data) { ... });
```

This will only write to the table if an item with id 'one' does not already exist.

Since you're using nodejs I'd suggest looking into using the [vogels](https://github.com/ryanfitz/vogels) library. The same ConditionExpression can be written as:

```
Event.create({id : "one", status : 'completed' }, {overwrite : false}, function (error, acc) { ... });
```

Comment: I have a list of string in an array.I need to check this string values are exist in dynamodb or not.And add the non existence value in newarray.I dont need to insert the non existence record in dynamodb.But the putItem with  ConditionExpressions does that insertion(non existing value) right.